# Unexpected Thread Runs Before Specific Action is Called

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating website with ASP.NET Core MVC, and I saw some threads which I didn't called are running, even the Action was not called.

These threads were seen while I debugging this static method:

```
    public static T ParseReader<T>(MySqlDataReader dataReader, bool closeReader = false) where T : new()
    {
        if (!dataReader.Read()) return default(T);

        T returnObject = new T();

        List<string> columnList = new List<string>();
        for (var i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; ++i)
            columnList.Add(dataReader.GetName(i));

        foreach (var column in columnList)
        {
            var property = returnObject.GetType().GetProperty(column);
            if (property == null || dataReader[column] == DBNull.Value)
                continue;

            var value = Convert.ChangeType(dataReader[column], property.PropertyType);
            property.SetValue(returnObject, value);
        }


        if (closeReader) dataReader.Close();

        return returnObject;
    }
```

The method is called when logged user calls specific action, and it seems that action is called before the user calls it.

what's the reason? it makes mess on my debugging!

Comment: Show the thread call stacks?

Comment: We are missing most of the context here. But all ASP.NET is inherently multi-threaded, so don't fight it and don't use `static` unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @Tratcher several worker threads are running, I think the Kestrel gets some signal and prefetch Action, then return to the user when he calls it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman then should I make singleton for it?

Comment: No, use the DI container.

Comment: Kestrel does no prefetching.